# Exception postGIS Geometry Mapping with JPA

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, postgis

I am using

Hibernate-Core 4.1.4 Final

Hibernate-spatial 4.0-M1

JTS 1.8

Hibernate-spatial-postgis 1.1.1

on JBoss 7.1 with JPA 2.0

I am trying to map a Geometry Column (OpenStreetMap Database with postgis) to an JPA-Entity like this:

```
import org.hibernate.annotations.Type;
import com.vividsolutions.jts.geom.Geometry;

@Type(type="org.hibernate.spatial.GeometryType")
@Column(name = "way", nullable = true)
private Geometry geom;
```

The Connection seems fine and other Columns are deserialized fine. With the geometry-column i get this exception:

```
 java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
at org.hibernate.spatial.GeometrySqlTypeDescriptor.getExtractor(GeometrySqlTypeDescriptor.java:57)
at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.nullSafeGet(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:269)
at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.nullSafeGet(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:265)
at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.nullSafeGet(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:238)
at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.hydrate(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:357)
```

...

Answer (score 0):

Like this post

http://hibernate-spatial.1140993.n2.nabble.com/Deserializing-my-Spatial-Objects-td6686115.html

I found that when I moved the annotation to the getter, the error went away